# y2019SO2.map is not a function error in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, air-quality

I have an error that I didn't understand. How can I fix this? This is my code.

```
// get the layer for the city
var antalya = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
        ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Antalya')));
Map.addLayer(antalya);
Map.centerObject(antalya,7);

// add image collection with filters
var y2019 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2")
  .filterDate("2019-04-01","2019-04-30")
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(antalya);
var y2020 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2")
  .filterDate("2020-04-01","2020-04-30")
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(antalya);

//hava kalitesi ölçüm istasyonu
var istasyon = ee.Geometry.Point([30.700425,36.914883]);
Map.addLayer(istasyon);

//clip the city from SO2 layers
var y2019SO2=y2019.median()
  .clip(antalya);
var y2020SO2=y2020.median()
  .clip(antalya);

// add layers to map(burası karışık!!)
Map.addLayer(y2019SO2,{min:0,max:0.001,palette:['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'purple', 'blue', 'white']},"April 2019");
Map.addLayer(y2020SO2,{min:0,max:0.001,palette:['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'purple', 'blue', 'white']},"April 2020");

var feats = y2019SO2.map(function(image){
  var reducer = ee.Reducer.median();
  var stats = image.reduceRegion(reducer, antalya, 1000);
  return ee.Feature(null, stats).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// plot that feature collectioin
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(feats, 'system:time_start')
                .setSeriesNames(['SO2 median']); // order is by default alfabetically
print(chart, feats);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because "y2019SO2" is an image and you cannot map over an image. You should map over "y2019".

I changed that part:

```
// get the layer for the city
var antalya = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
        ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Antalya')));
Map.addLayer(antalya);
Map.centerObject(antalya,7);

// add image collection with filters
var y2019 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2")
  .filterDate("2019-04-01","2019-04-30")
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(antalya);
var y2020 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2")
  .filterDate("2020-04-01","2020-04-30")
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(antalya);

//hava kalitesi ölçüm istasyonu
var istasyon = ee.Geometry.Point([30.700425,36.914883]);
Map.addLayer(istasyon);

var feats = y2019.map(function(image){
  var y2019SO2 = image.clip(antalya)
  var reducer = ee.Reducer.median();
  var stats = y2019SO2.reduceRegion(reducer, antalya, 1000);
  return ee.Feature(null, stats).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
});

// plot that feature collectioin
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(feats, 'system:time_start')
                .setSeriesNames(['SO2 median']); // order is by default alfabetically
print(chart, feats);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I see, when I use y2019, the chart is for whole part but I want to plot time serie chart for antalya part.

Comment: As you see in the var feats = ..., I used: var y2019SO2 = image.clip(antalya). This clips the image collection by antalya part.

Comment: Yes I saw it. The graphs don't seem like I expected. They are not matched with the graphs plotted from the other data. I confused because of that reason.